# Type object 'Model' has no attribute 'objects' - when it's clearly there..?

Tags: django

I'm getting this error when I try to create a new object via `Book.objects.create()`:

```
AttributeError: type object 'Book' has no attribute 'objects'
```

For this code:

```
# models.py

class BookManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(BookManager, self).get_queryset().filter(type="book")

    def create(self, **kwargs):
        return super(BookManager, self).create(**kwargs)


class ChapterManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(ChapterManager, self).get_queryset().filter(type="chapter")

    def create(self, **kwargs):
        return super(ChapterManager, self).create(**kwargs)


class Text(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)  # for STI

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Text, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # If we don't have a subclass at all, then we need the type attribute to match
        # our current class.
        if not self.__class__.__subclasses__():
            self.type = self.__class__.__name__.lower()
        else:
            subclass = [
                x
                for x in self.__class__.__subclasses__()
                if x.__name__.lower() == self.type
            ]
            if subclass:
                self.__class__ = subclass[0]
            else:
                self.type = self.__class__.__name__.lower()


class Chapter(Text):
    objects = ChapterManager()

    class Meta:
        proxy = True


class Book(Text):
    objects = BookManager()

    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

Where you can see the `Chapter` and `Book` objects clearly have an `objects` field pointing to the custom manager...

For some more context, I'm using [single table inheritance](https://schinckel.net/2013/07/28/django-single-table-inheritance-on-the-cheap./) for my models.

This exact same code works fine for another project I have so I have no clue what's happening.

Comment: Your code looks fine, can you past the full traceback and the code that is producing the error?

Comment: @IainShelvington - There's nothing else in the error. This is the full error message when I run a ```Book.objects.create()``` tests: ```ERROR: test_test (library.tests.tests_models.Book)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/library/tests/tests_models.py", line 14, in test_test
    Book.objects.create()
AttributeError: type object 'Book' has no attribute 'objects'```

Comment: The strangest thing is that if ```Book.objects.create()``` works fine in ```python manage.py shell```...... I'm updating the comment with my ```test.py``` file but it's pretty basic/standard too...

Comment: Ahhhh looks like my Test class didn't have "TestCase" appended to the end. Problem solved. Thanks.

Comment: Unrelated tip: super doesn't need to use the class name. e.g.: `super(ChapterManager, self).create(**kwargs)` can be shortened to `super().create(**kwargs)` in Python3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My test.py class didn't end in TestCase. I.e. it should be `class TestTestCase(TestCase):` and not `class Test(TestCase):`